# Manual FTP with commons.net.ftp

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to use apache commons to send manual FTP commands as I have to send non-standard FTP commands to a specific server (that accepts them)

Before I try to send these non-standard commands I want to get FTP working manually with commons.net.ftp. Unfortunately I seem to be missing something.

**This works fine** (i.e. it retrieves the list of files)

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig();
ftp.configure(config);

ftp.connect("ftp.mozilla.org");
ftp.login("anonymous", "");

ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
FTPFile[] fileList = ftp.listFiles("/");
```

**This doesn't**

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig();
ftp.configure(config);

ftp.connect("ftp.mozilla.org");
ftp.login("anonymous", "");

ftp.sendCommand("PASV");
ftp.sendCommand("NLST");
```

I get the appropriate response for `ftp.sendCommand("PASV");` but it times out on `ftp.sendCommand("NLST");` finally giving me

```
425 Failed to establish connection.
```

I have tried to research the topic but most advice on this error is for people setting up servers (and it's usually a firewall problem).

Why does it work when `net.ftp` does it, but not when I send the commands manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the `PASV` command manually is not enough, the client has to open the data connection to the port specified by the server in response to the `PASV` command. This is performed by calling the `enterLocalPassiveMode()` method. Since sending `PASV` manually doesn't initialize the data connection you get an error shortly after.

See http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#passive for more details on the FTP protocol.

Comment: None of the examples I have seen have any command between `PASV` and `RETR` or `LIST` / `NLST`

Comment: Because the connection opened doesn't translate into a specific command, the client just connects to a port on the server. See http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#passive for more details.

Comment: In that example, the client issues `PASV` immediately followed by `LIST`... this is what I am doing and it fails. Sorry but I still don't see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ahh I finally got it.. I followed the process in `telnet` and then i used `wget` in another terminal on the port that `PASV` specified.. I see what you mean now

Comment: The FTP protocol relies on two connections. The first one for issuing the commands (on port 21), and the second one for the data. The data connection is either opened by the server (active mode) or by the client (passive mode). When you send the `PASV` command the server tells what port to use, but you don't actually connect to this port unless you use the dedicated method in the API to enter the passive mode. Sending PASV manually doesn't open the data connection automatically.